# Parse Date from string present in multiple formats into datetime format

Tags: python, datetime, parsing

I have a string which may contain date into any of the below format

```
20200618
18-june-2020
```

Could someone please help me in how to obtain the date from the string?
Thanks

Comment: I am not sure whether there is a library that does it by itself, but if those are the only two formats, you can use regexp to check what is your date's format and then convert it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dateutil's parser can help:

```
from dateutil import parser

for d in ["20200618", "18-june-2020"]:
    print(parser.parse(d))
    
2020-06-18 00:00:00
2020-06-18 00:00:00
```